# how can you create an app.use() to attach data from database to res object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux-form

I have database data that will always be needed to loaded to the route `'domain/form-a/new'` and the query to the db is always the same to get necessary information for the form. Instead of another http to the server sometime after the DOM loads.

I would like a middleware to the route `` app.use(`/form-a/new') `` to somehow attach data to the response object before I send it with the html express.static() not sure how I can do this.

but i think i can only do something on the client like another http req after the form component renders on the page, because when `'domain/form-a/new'` gets requested, React intervenes and the Express server doesnt serve anything new.

The expected results is to set the state of the form component and createContext for the field values in that form with `<select />` and `<checkbox />`s with the help of the database.

Comment: Your question is apparently entirely unclear.  You're referencing `express.static()`, but apparently that isn't what you're really asking about at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can add middleware that will match any specified route and attach to the `req` object by mutating the `req` object.

```
cosnt express  = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/form-a/new', (req, res, next) => {
    // db request for middlewareData
    req.middlewareData = { 'middlewareData' }
    next()
}

app.get('/from-a/new', (req, res) => {
    // you can now use req.middleWare to access data from db
    res.send(req.middlewareData)
}

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: This isn't what the question asked.  The question asked how to attach data to a file that was being sent with `express.static()`.

Comment: I guess we'll wait for some clarification in that case

Comment: Look at the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs in the question.  This doesn't answer the questions in either of those.

Comment: I think this is not an express question but a react question. I don't think its express.static, but rather something to do with react router <Route match='form-a/new' exact /> ill have to edit it

Comment: I can add in the template option if that would be helpful to you

Comment: @Maddocks - Sorry  I wasted my time trying to help.  Your question is NOT clear at all.  Your  explicitly asked about modifying an `express.static()` response.  That's exactly what I answered, but it appears that what you wrote isn't what you are trying to ask and my answer was accumulating downvotes for who knows what reasons.  Please clarify your question.  I'll opt out now.

Comment: @NathanFries im not sure if i can use express to sort this one out since when the person enters in ```'/form-a/new'``` react router renders the correct page. so i will have to do somehting with componentDidMount() instead